# Supporting CNAME aliases

Tags: dns, cname

Im having trouble finding resources on what is involved in supporting CNAME aliases. If I have user accounts a yoursubdomain.myapp.com I would like users to be able to create a CNAME record that points yourdomain.com to this. What is involved on my side to get this to work? I understand users will have to add the record to there DNS. Do you I have to do some special stuff on my servers?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are describing is name-based virtual hosts.  You can learn how to configure this on Apache [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: Do you think this is something that could be set up to do it automatically or can it only be done manually?

Comment: Looks like your question was answered on ServerFault:

http://serverfault.com/questions/6920/automatically-connect-subdomains-to-directories-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

Aliases (CNAME records) are like pointers in programming. The target has nothing to do and cannot even prevent being pointed at.